# Trying to group two models on a show page and have them show based on have the same data rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It might be a little hard to explain but I am going to do my best. I have a page that features a list of things (Income, amount put into savings, and the month/year the list was made) and a separate model that lists items (name of the item, cost of the item, what kind of item it is, and the month/year the item was made) I want to group them based on the month they where both made, so if a list was made in august of 2017 the item will be put under/on the same list. How would I do this? I'm kinda new to rails and still learning so I apologize if this is a really easy thing to do but I haven't really been able to find anything online.

show.html.erb:

```
 <% @user.lists.each do |list| %>
    <p>Monthly Income: <%= list.income %></p>
    <p>Amount put into savings:<%= list.put_into_savings %></p>
    <p>Month <%= list.month %></p>
 <% end %>

 <% if @list.month === @item.month %>
   <% @user.items.each do |item| %>
     <p>Item: <%= item.item_name %></p>
     <p>Cost: <%= item.item_cost %></p>
     <p>Group: <%= item.item_waste %></p>
     <p><%= item.item_group%></p>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Div with code as asked for

```
<div class="lists_wrapper">
  <div class="list">
  <% @user.lists.each do |list| %>

     <p>Monthly Income: <%= list.income %></p>
     <p>Amount put into savings:<%= list.put_into_savings %></p>
     <p>Month <%= list.month %></p>

    <% @user.items.where(month: list.month).each do |item| %>
      <p>Item: <%= item.item_name %></p>
      <p>Cost: <%= item.item_cost %></p>
      <p>Group: <%= item.item_waste %></p>
      <p>Month: <%= item.month %> </p>
      <p><%= item.item_group%></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am a litte confused.  Does the list contain the collection of items you want to show, but you just want to be able to restrict it by the month that the list ws made, or is items a completely separate model that no other relationship to list?

Comment: items is completely different with no relationships to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` ([an activerecord query method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)) regardless of relationship exist between two model.

```
<div class="lists_wrapper">
  <% @user.lists.each do |list| %>
    <p>Monthly Income: <%= list.income %></p>
    <p>Amount put into savings:<%= list.put_into_savings %></p>
    <p>Month <%= list.month %></p>

    <div class="list">
      <% @user.items.where(month: list.month).each do |item| %>
       <p>Item: <%= item.item_name %></p>
       <p>Cost: <%= item.item_cost %></p>
       <p>Group: <%= item.item_waste %></p>
       <p><%= item.item_group%></p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: A follow up question, it seems like it is only working for 1 item at a time, I have the exact code you posted but if I create 2 items with the same month, one will be included in the correct div and the other wont be, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @firewire167 what happen to the other one ? does it display outside div or hidden ?

Comment: it displays outside of the div

Comment: I added it to the post above

Comment: @firewire167 your code looked look like it was missing few things. I have updated my code to include the div, use that.

Comment: Your updated code groups everything into the same Div. What I am looking for is to have every list in its own div, and all the items that belong to that list via having the same month in the same div as the list it belongs to. I want every list to be able to have more then one item, the code before your edit was limiting it to only 1 item per list for some reason which was the issue. I'm sorry if I haven't been explaining this very well, and I really appreciate all the help.